# Can I make method return values non-discardable in C#

Tags: c#

## Example

I have a static method like this:

```
public static MyClass CreateMyClass()
{
  return new MyClass()
  {
    Foo = "SomeVal",
    Bar = 123
  };
}
```

Now it occurred, that this function was called like this.

```cs
public class ConsumerClass
{
  public ConsumerClass
  {
    CreatePluginUpdateProcess();
    // oopsie, should have been
    // myClass = CreatePluginUpdateProcess();
  }

  private MyClass myClass;
}
```

## Question

How can I cause this code to emit a warning, or an error. What I am looking for is an attribute that I can mark my `CreateMyClass()` method with, so that the Compiler will warn when the return value is ignored.

## Alternative phrasing of question

In C++ there is the [[[nodiscard]]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard) attribute. Which causes a warning when ignoring the return value of a function marked with [[nodiscard]].

So an alternative way to phrase this question is: What is the C# equivalent of the C++ [[nodiscard]] attribute.

Comment: Instead of a return type, you could use an out parameter: `public static void CreateMyClass(out MyClass obj);`

Comment: Or you can write your own Analyzer.

Comment: Rozlyn Code Analyzer - not sure if that would be "over the top"? - Some references: [Write Better Code Faster with Roslyn Analyzers](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/write-better-code-faster-with-roslyn-analyzers/) , [Overview of .NET source code analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/overview), [Code analysis (dotnet Framework)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/code-analyzers)

Comment: ^^ Further: [How to write a Roslyn Analyzer](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-to-write-a-roslyn-analyzer/) and [Tutorial: Write your first analyzer and code fix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix)

Comment: Even with an `out` parameter, you can discard or ignore that result (`CreateMyClass(out _ )`)